# django css path

Tags: css, django, path

i want to include a css file into the header of my documents, but i have a few questions:
1.Where should i set the path to media, and it should be a relative/absolute path? In settings.py, i 've tried setting MEDIA_URL but my style is still 'unseen'
2.how can i make the htmls to inheric that syle (for not adding the href in every page)?

i've tryed writing like:

```
<link href="/media/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

having set

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

but it doesn't work.
media is a folder inside my project

shold i set the Media _root to? how should this be done?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you also need to handle the url that serves the file,
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/